# can you append form data to a URL in a phonegap webapp?

Tags: forms, web-applications, cordova

In my phonegap webapp, I have a form with some serious GET action on it. When I click submit, I want to open a new page and extract the form data from the URL with javascript.

Question: can you do that in a phonegap app, when you're not actually in a browser?

Comment: don't bother answering--> I figured it out. I just don't have enough reputation to answer my own question during the first 8 hours after asking. ill fill in an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! It's as simple as I said:

```
<form action="destinationpage.html" action="GET>
Input your data:<input type="text" name="data /> <br />
<input type="submit" value ="Continue">
</form>
```

Then see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763363/how-to-pass-form-information-onto-a-google-map-on-a-separate-page) for retrieving your data on the next page!